# When to declare static property?

Tags: php, oop, properties

I often get confused whether I'd better use static property or just public one.
For example, I have a class `EventDispatcher` and I want to have max listeners and auto trigger configuration.
Is this one better

```
<?php
class EventDispatcher
{
    public static $auto_trigger = 0;
    public static $max_listeners = 30;
```

or this one

```
<?php
class EventDispatcher
{
    public $auto_trigger = 0;
    public $max_listeners = 30;
```

So, which one is better?
I'm confused because the property is rather a 'configuration' property than just basic property.

I often get confused in choosing between static or not though I know that the static one is like global class, very accessible. But in the practical case, it's still difficult to choose.

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo You misunderstood my question..It's not duplicate..If I make it in other words, my questions is like 'Static, When to use instead of constants or public property??'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Overall it depends on what you're going to be using the property for, but I usually avoid using static ones, because you can call them from anywhere without making an instance of the object and I prefer some encapsulation, having getters and setters, etc.

If you know the property is something that is not going to change, I'd suggest to use a constant instead, which you can also access without making an instance of the object:

```
class BookModel {
    const TABLE_NAME = 'books';
}

echo BookModel::TABLE_NAME;
```

Otherwise I'd advise you to keep your properties non-static so they'll be tied to an object instance and you could make a getter and setter for it.

Comment: Alright, so the point is... Never use static property, right? Because we can use constants instead, right?

Comment: And, Never use public property, right?  
Since we should make it in setter and getter to make things run properly, so always use private property, right?

Comment: Well "never" is a bit of extreme, but generally you'll make less mistakes and your code will be cleaner, because you'll be getting and setting your property through a single method, meaning you won't repeat yourself if you have to do some operations with the property.

Comment: "static" has another peculiarity - late static binding, it allows you to make transactions that are not made with the "const" ... http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php

Comment: _because you can call them from anywhere without making an instance of the object_ .. this might be true for public accessible properties and/or methods but not when the visibility is hidden from outside the class with `private` or `protected`. I wouldn't know a solution for a singleton pattern without the usage of static .. The rest of your answer I fully agree ;)